Trying to extract information from pdf files in google colab. It is just repeating most information from the first file into all the others
This is the code:
for file in files.get('files', []):
    # ... (Get file content as before)

    # Extract data from the PDF
    pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(BytesIO(file_content))
    page = pdf_reader.pages[0]  # Assuming you want to extract from the first page

    # 1. File Name
    file_name = file['name']
    print(f"File: {file_name}")

    # 2. Process Number
    process_number = None
    process_number_match = None
    process_number_match = re.search(r"(\d{7}-\d{2}.\d{4}.\d.\d{2}.\d{4})", page.extract_text())
    if process_number_match:
        process_number = process_number_match.group(1)
        print(f"Process Number: {process_number}")
    else:
        print("erro, número do processo não encontrado")

    # 3. Name
    name = None  # Reset the name variable
    name_match = None
    name_match = re.search(r"(AUTOR|INTERESSADOS|INTERESSADO|INTERESSADA):\s+([A-Z\s]+)", page.extract_text())
    if name_match:
        name = name_match.group(2)
        print(f"Name: {name}")
    else:
        print("error, nome não encontrado")

    # 4. Keywords
    found_keywords = []  # Reset the found_keywords list
    keywords = ["audiência", "subsídios", "cumprimento"]
    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword in page.extract_text():
            found_keywords.append(keyword)
    if found_keywords:
        print(f"Keywords Found: {', '.join(found_keywords)}")
    else:
        print("erro, pedido não encontrado")

It will keep printing this:
Keywords Found: cumprimento
File: 33-00737.015338.pdf
Process Number: (number1)
Name:(name1)
 
S
Keywords Found: cumprimento
File: 32-00737.012571.pdf
Process Number: (number1)
Name:(name1)
 
S
Keywords Found: cumprimento
File: 31-00737.012592.pdf
Process Number: (number1)
Name:(name1)
 
S
Keywords Found: cumprimento
File: 30-00737.010470.pdf
Process Number: (number1)
Name:(name1)
 
S
Keywords Found: cumprimento
File: 29-00737.007060.pdf
Process Number: (number1)
Name:(name1)

The file number is getting updated, so it is reading the correct files. But it keeps repeating the other strings. I tried reseting it with = None, but didn't work.
Tried using
# 3. Name
    name = None  # Reset the name variable
    name_match = None
    name_match = re.search(r"(AUTOR|INTERESSADOS|INTERESSADO|INTERESSADA):\s+([A-Z\s]+)", page.extract_text())
    if name_match:
        name = name_match.group(2)
        print(f"Name: {name}")
    else:
        print("error, nome não encontrado")

I was expecting to print the name for each document. Instead I got the name right for the first document and it got repeated for all the others.

Can you add raw inputs and expected outputs, in your question?

Try something like this. Note that ([A-Z\s]+) will also fail. But, I can't fix it without seeing some inputs.

describe problem in question's body, not in title.

did you assign new value to page? Maybe you all time use the same page. Or maybe use all time the same file_content. OR maybe all files have the same information. Maybe display page.extract_text() to see what you get from file.

Unfortunatelly I can't put the raw inputs, they are sensible information.

Thanks, user24716492! I'll take a look
Furas: I'll try it, thanks!
